# How to get node text without children?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I use Nokogiri for parse the html page with same content:

```
<p class="parent">
  Useful text
  <br>
  <span class="child">Useless text</span>
</p>
```

When I call the method `page.css('p.parent').text` Nokogiri returns 'Useful text Useless text'. But I need only 'Useful text'.

How to get node text without children?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

XPath includes the `text()` node test for selecting text nodes, so you could do:

```
page.xpath('//p[@class="parent"]/text()')
```

Using XPath to select HTML classes can become quite tricky if the element in question could belong to more than one class, so this might not be ideal.

Fortunately Nokogiri adds the `text()` selector to CSS, so you can use:

```
page.css('p.parent > text()')
```

to get the text nodes that are direct children of `p.parent`. This will also return some nodes that are whtespace only, so you may have to filter them out.

Comment: The text() selector seems to be most clean solution. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `page.css('p.parent').children.remove`.

Then your `page.css('p.parent').text` will return the text without the children nodes.

Note: the `page` will be modified by the `remove`